# Why is the causative translated in these sentences like that?

Tags: grammaire, constructions-causatives

[image]

This is from a book called Practice Makes Perfect Complete French Grammar from page 117  and here's its link : (https://archive.org/details/practice-makes-perfect-complete-french-grammar/page/n33)

I wonder why *J'ai fait tremper les pruneaux* is translated as *I **soaked** the prunes* and not as sth like  : *I'm having the prunes soaked*,  *I'm causing the prunes to be soaked* or *I'm getting the prunes soaked* instead, and the same of course applies for the other sentences. Is it just a mistake or am I missing sth about the causative in French?
I checked an advanced resource : (https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/faire-causative/) but still found nothing though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*J'ai fait tremper les pruneaux.* doesn't mean you had someone doing it for you but that you had something doing it for you:

> I put the prunes into water for them to be soaked.

Similarly, *j'ai fait griller le pain* means:

> I put the bread in a toaster which toasted the bread.

The most natural translation of these sentences seems to be:

> I soaked the prunes
>
> I toasted the bread

Unless it would have been done by someone else, I don't think it would be idiomatic English to say:

> I had the bread toasted (by the toaster).
>
> I had the chicken roasted (by the oven).

while in French, it is usual.

We are probably less likely to say the following sentences, but they are fine too:

> J'ai rôti le poulet.
>
> J'ai grillé le pain.

Moreover, your suggestions do not match the French sentences tense. Both

> I'm having the prunes soaked
>
> I'm getting the prunes soaked

are taking place in the (continuous) present while "*j'ai fait* something" happened in the past and is done now.

Comment: I also understood that it was because the natural use of the verb is intransitive -- the something you're causing to *griller* is the bread itself. What do you think?

Comment: @Luke A good reason too indeed. With purely intransitive verbs, that's the only option: *j'ai fait disparaître le lapin* and not *j'ai disparu le lapin* ;-)